# Named anchors in (i)frames aren't jumped to

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, firefox

I have html page(parent page) that contains a iframe(child page inside this iframe),
this java script function get the location where i want to scroll iframe using internal page linking.

```
function scrollToAnchor () 
        {   //function parseParameter return the query string value from the url    
            var anchor = parseParameter(window.location.href,'anchor');

            if (anchor != null)
            {   
                location.hash=anchor;

            }
        }
but anchor value in iframe page source not in parant page,
```

this is not able to scroll the iframe page.how to scroll iframe page through parant page,

it works in IE and `Crome` but doesn't work in `firefox`. there is any alternative of this code.please suggest.
my parant page url is

```
http://localhost:8989/schoolforms/SelectForm?formTypeID=STUDENT_EMERGENCY
```

This is my `window.location.href"` value that is for iframe

```
http://localhost:8088/schoolforms/StudentEmergency?student=B874BCC3EA5B83670988C959E9F0036B&anchor=InsuranceInfo
```

after parsing anchor contains `InsuranceInfo` after this function url becomes like

```
http://localhost:8088/schoolforms/StudentEmergency?student=B874BCC3EA5B83670988C959E9F0036B&anchor=InsuranceInfo#InsuranceInfo
```

Comment: What does your anchor tag look like

Comment: hahaha, I'm sorry, but I laughed out loud on that answer :D

Comment: @DominicGreen and michal B.  please read my problem again.if u got it,because of i'm not developed this application my understanding was not clear.i'm working only bug fixing in application so.....

Answer (score 0):

JQuery bbq has a nice 'deparam' function

https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/

```
var params = $.deparam.querystring(); 
window.location.hash = params['anchor']
```

Comment: please read my problem again.if u got it,because of i'm not developed this application my understanding was not clear.i'm working only bug fixing in application so.....

Answer (score 0):

Too many missing information to understand what exacly do you want to achieve. I guess that you need to scroll your page to the anchor with id from anchor variable of **window.location.href**.

I don't know how works your function parseParameter() and I need to believe that is working good.

**location.hash** contains the part of URL after # for example #news etc. So if you pass a string to **location.hash** browser will add this string to URL and scroll to the html element with the same ID.

**EFFECT**

```
http://localhost:8088/schoolforms/StudentEmergency?student=B874BCC3EA5B83670988C959E9F0036B&anchor=InsuranceInfo#InsuranceInfo
```

It's not a good way, because after that you will have both anchor variable and hash in your URL.

**TRY THIS**

```
function scrollToAnchor () 
{   
    var anchor = parseParameter(window.location.href,'anchor'); 

    if (anchor != null)
    {   
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+anchor).offset().top}, 0);
    }
}
```

I used .animate() because if you want you can change in this line 0 to for example default value, which is 400 (i guess ms unit) and it will scroll with animation (delay). If you leave 0 it will scroll to the element immediately without any delay.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+anchor).offset().top}, 400);
```

Comment: @london it's give me error as: TypeError: $(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+anchor).offset().top}, 0);

Comment: @dev I forgot to add that you need to load JQuery library. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi Landon, i've added that and try with ur good idea but not woking in firefox

Comment: please read my problem again.if u got it,because of i'm not developed this application my understanding was not clear.i'm working only bug fixing in application so.......